# throw exception in lambda - java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm using lambda expressions. What is the equivalent of this:

```
for (Integer id: ids) {
    if (!repository.exists(id)) {
        throw new Exception .....
    }
}
```

I tried using this:

```
ids.stream().filter(id-> repository.exists(idStatut)).findAny().orElseThrow(() ->
                new Exception...
            );
```

But it doesn't work well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your original loop, you want to throw an exception if any of the `Integer`s don't pass the filter:

```
if (ids.stream().anyMatch(id -> !repository.exists(id)))
    throw new Exception ...
```

Comment: Thank you ! I wasted all morning on it -_-"